# Create custom jquery function to select all on focus for given element types

Tags: jquery

I often have several views in our web app that we'd like to specify certain inputs and text areas (those with a `selectAll` class for example) to select all on focus. The code in the function below works great, but since we use it a lot, we'd prefer to have a common function to call.

As such, my attempt below, which is not working, is to have this custom jquery function (not sure if that is the correct term...maybe plugin?)

```
$.fn.selectAllOnFocus = function () {
    $('body').on('focus', this, function (e) {
        $(this)
            .one('mouseup', function () {
                $(this).select();
                return false;
            })
            .select();
    }); 
};
```

Then call it as such for a given selector:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(function($){
        $('input.selectAll, textarea.selectAll').selectAllOnFocus();
    });

</script>
```

I've tried wrapping the `this` variable in the `.on` parameters in a jquery instantiator (again, I may be making up that term to mean something it doesn't :) ), as in `$(this)` to no avail. As you can tell, I'm not the strongest at jquery, what am I missing?

Comment: `$('body').on('focus', this, function (e) {` <= this is the first code smell I see.  It looks like you are trying to create a delegate event handler, but you are using a jQuery object as the second parameter, instead of a child selector string.

Comment: I'm also slightly unclear about the desired result.  Are you trying to make it so that when any of the elements gets focus, that `select()` is performed on all of them?

Comment: @Taplar the desired result is to select all text in the input when it gets focus. That code works fine, it is just the process of trying to make it a re-usable function that is at issue. I agree, on the first code smell, but not sure how to fix it. Can you convert the jquery object to it's selector string and use that as the parameter? i.e. `this.selector`..ah yes, that worked!

Comment: By your usage of a delegate event handler, are you wanting this logic to work for future elements that are created that match the selectors, without having to call this logic again?

Answer (score 0):

I was close. Needed to get the selector property of the jquery object

```
$.fn.selectAllOnFocus = function () {
$('body').on('focus', this.selector, function (e) {
    $(this)
        .one('mouseup', function () {
            $(this).select();
            return false;
        })
        .select();
});
```

};